# tamely branched cover over P^1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, characteristic-p

k is an algebraically closed field, X is a smooth, connected, projective curve over k. f: X-->P^1 is a finite morphism. Let t be a parameter of P^1, suppose f is etale outside t=0 and t=\infty, and tamely ramified over these two points. Prove that f is a cyclic cover, i.e., K(X)=k(t)[h]/(h^n-ut), u is a unit in field k.

Comment: By Hurewicz's formula I can prove the ramification indices at these two points are n, n is the degree of f. But I can't see why it must be a cyclic cover.

Comment: By the way, I think you mean (Adolf) Hurwitz, rather than (Wittold) Hurewicz.

Comment: yes, you are right~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to think about it:

You can easily deduce from Riemann-Hurwitz that the genus of X is 0, i.e. it is just the projective line. Look at the affine patch: t is not infinity. Above t=infinity there's only one point. So take that point out, and call the parameter of the resulting affine line h. Then we have the inclusion of k[t] in k[h]. So t=g(h) where g is a polynomial. Since over t=0 there is one point with ramification n, g has multiplicity n: g=u(h-c)<sup>n</sup>. So after change of variables g=u*h<sup>n</sup>, as required.

Answer (score 4):

Take the Galois closure, which satisfies the same hypotheses and is Galois.  The hardest part is to see that it is again *tamely* ramified: for this see Theorem 2.1 of

http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/248APage/handouts/tamecomp.pdf.

Then observe that the tame fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^1$ minus two points is procyclic.  This follows from a comparison theorem of Grothendieck, which allows you to reduce to the case $k = \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: For those who like references, the comparison theorem which gives the result about the tame fundamental group of $\mathbf P^1$ minus two points as a corollary is SGA 1 Exp. XIII 2.12.